# SQL Server stored procedure returning Null instead of an INtT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
@upc AS VARCHAR(13) = NULL,
@cert_code AS VARCHAR(15) = NULL,
@vendor AS INT = NULL,
@count AS INT = 0 OUTPUT,
@store AS VARCHAR(3) = NULL,
@corporate AS VARCHAR = Null,
@zone AS VARCHAR = Null,
@region AS VARCHAR = Null,
@class AS VARCHAR = Null
AS
BEGIN   -- Added for new functionality
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    If @store IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        -- Get the storeID from Stores
        DECLARE @storeID AS INT

        SELECT @storeID = StoreID
        FROM Enterprise..Stores
        WHERE Store = @store
    END

    IF @storeID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @cert_code IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsStore
            WHERE (StoreID = @storeID) AND (upc = @upc)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @vendor IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
                FROM Enterprise..ProductsStore
                WHERE (StoreID = @storeID) AND (cert_code = @cert_code)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
                FROM Enterprise..ProductsStore
                WHERE (StoreID = @storeID) 
                  AND (cert_code = @cert_code) AND (vendor = @vendor)
            END
        END
    END
END

If @zone IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF @cert_code IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
        FROM Enterprise..ProductsZone
        WHERE (upc = @upc)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @vendor IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsZone
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsZone
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code) AND (vendor = @vendor)
        END
    END
END

IF @region IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF @cert_code IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
        FROM Enterprise..ProductsRegion
        WHERE (upc = @upc)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @vendor IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsRegion
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsRegion
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code) AND (vendor = @vendor)
        END
    END
END

IF @class IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF @cert_code IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
        FROM Enterprise..ProductsClass
        WHERE (upc = @upc)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @vendor IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsClass
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsClass
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code) AND (vendor = @vendor)
        END
    END
END

IF @corporate IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF @cert_code IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
        FROM Enterprise..ProductsMaster
        WHERE (upc = @upc)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @vendor IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsMaster
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsMaster
            WHERE (cert_code = @cert_code) AND (vendor = @vendor)
        END
    END
END
GO
```

When I have `@store IS NOT NULL` it counts and returns an `INT` as expected, however when one of `@corporate`, `@zone`, `@region`, `@class` is set as NOT NULL, I am getting an output of null instead of an INT like expected.

What is the problem here?

Comment: You've got a little too much going on here.  Can you provide example param value for every variable passed in for your output = null case?  I'm unsure how many of them are null at any one time.

Comment: Also can you trace which select statement is the issue?  Maybe replace them one by one with SELECT 999 and see if it returns 999 instead of null?  If that doesn't help maybe try deleting bits until you have a smaller case that returns NULL so we can rule some of it out?

Comment: If you add `SET @count =0` to the start (just after `SET NOCOUNT ON;`) does your proc work? You might not have an `ELSE` branch in there picking it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its a typo error or something else but please check you begin and ends for the IF and ELSE
From what I see the procedure ends within this set of codes as the END matches the BEGIN of the main stored procedure.

```
@upc AS VARCHAR(13) = NULL,
@cert_code AS VARCHAR(15) = NULL,
@vendor AS INT = NULL,
@count AS INT = 0 OUTPUT,
@store AS VARCHAR(3) = NULL,
@corporate AS VARCHAR = Null,
@zone AS VARCHAR = Null,
@region AS VARCHAR = Null,
@class AS VARCHAR = Null
AS
BEGIN   -- Added for new functionality
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    If @store IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        -- Get the storeID from Stores
        DECLARE @storeID AS INT

        SELECT @storeID = StoreID
        FROM Enterprise..Stores
        WHERE Store = @store
    END

    IF @storeID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @cert_code IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
            FROM Enterprise..ProductsStore
            WHERE (StoreID = @storeID) AND (upc = @upc)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @vendor IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
                FROM Enterprise..ProductsStore
                WHERE (StoreID = @storeID) AND (cert_code = @cert_code)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
                FROM Enterprise..ProductsStore
                WHERE (StoreID = @storeID) 
                  AND (cert_code = @cert_code) AND (vendor = @vendor)
            END
        END
    END
END -- This End is wrong should not be here
```

If this is just a typo please post the codes properly. 
Also as others have pointed out initialize the @count parameter as zero.
It seems the remaining part of the procedure is never executed and as @count is not initialized it returns Null

Comment: This is spot on, My main statements Begin is matched with the end before if '@zone'. the rest of my procedure is not running thus '@count' is never assigned. Thanks

Comment: @user3838756 Did you not read my answer when I said the same thing right after you posted?

Answer (score 1):

None of your queries should be able to assign a null to your `@count` variable since they all use the `count()` aggregate. That means none of the queries is ever run.

I do think the `end` just prior to the `if @zone` is wrong. But I'm pretty sure that the `end` at the end of the procedure definition must be the end of the batch. Maybe I'm wrong and your proc is actually ending earlier than you expected?

You can certainly compress a lot of that branching into your queries. Here's my attempt at it. I pared down most of the indentation and begin/end pairs.

```
declare @storeID as int;
if @store is not null
begin
    -- Get the storeID from Stores
    SELECT  @storeID = StoreID
    FROM    Enterprise..Stores
    WHERE   Store = @store;

    if @storeID is not null
    SELECT  @count = COUNT(*)
    FROM    Enterprise..ProductsStore
    WHERE   StoreID = @storeID and 
            (
                    @cert_code is null and upc_code = @upc_code
                or  cert_code = @cert_code and (vendor = @vendor or @vendor is null)
            );
end

if @zone is not null
SELECT  @count = COUNT(*)
FROM    Enterprise..ProductsZone
WHERE       @cert_code is null and upc_code = @upc_code
        or  cert_code = @cert_code and (vendor = @vendor or @vendor is null);

if @region is not null
SELECT  @count = COUNT(*)
FROM    Enterprise..ProductsRegion
WHERE       @cert_code is null and upc_code = @upc_code
        or  cert_code = @cert_code and (vendor = @vendor or @vendor is null);

if @class is not null
SELECT  @count = COUNT(*)
FROM    Enterprise..ProductsClass
WHERE       @cert_code is null and upc_code = @upc_code
        or  cert_code = @cert_code and (vendor = @vendor or @vendor is null);
```

Comment: `@count AS INT = 0 OUTPUT` is not initialization of the parameter, it is default value of the parameter, if the parameter value is not explicitly provided during the call of the procedure. So, it is possible to have `@count` with the `NULL` value at the beginning of the procedure.

Comment: Yeah, I kept forgetting it was a procedure. You're right about that.

Answer (score 1):

Why you put varchar?
Use bellow code.

```
@corporate AS VARCHAR(max) = NULL,
@zone AS VARCHAR(max) = NULL,
@region AS VARCHAR(max) = NULL,
@class AS VARCHAR(max) = NULL
```

Comment: Good to note. But won't the counts still be zero rather than null when the arguments are truncated?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, as it would effect my output, however this did not solve my original problem.